# Volley request gives Runtime Exception : Bad URL

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to do a GET request on a URL and get JSON response, however I am getting the **Bad URL** error even after I have tried using **http:// and .json** extensions. The URL works pretty much fine in the browser as I tested it and gives the Json with the get parameters. I even tried surrounding the below code with try and catch exceptions but that didn't help as well. Please check the code and the logcat output and help me.

Code :

```
final String badUrl = "http://acbcs.co/whosonline.php?token="+token+"&gps="+glong+"&gpslat="+glat;

            JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, badUrl , null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!
                            try {
                                response = response.getJSONObject("msg");
                                String site = response.getString("msg");
                                String theusers = response.getString("online");

                                if (site.equals("Error adding user!")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {

                                    int len = getStrings (theusers,":").length;
                                    concat=new String[len];
                                    concat=getStrings (theusers,":");

                                    usern = new String[len];
                                    glatn = new String[len];

                                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                                        String arrtemp[]=new String[getStrings (concat[i]," ").length];;
                                        arrtemp=getStrings (concat[i]," ");
                                        if(arrtemp[i].length()>0) {
                                            usern[i] = arrtemp[0];
                                            glatn[i] = arrtemp[1]+" *"+arrtemp[2];
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            usern[i] = "Your Location";
                                            glatn[i] = glat+" *"+glong;
                                        }



                                        if(togglemap%2==0){
                                            webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            String removeusern = Arrays.toString(usern).replace("[","");
                                            removeusern = removeusern.replace("]","");
                                            removeusern = removeusern.replace(", null","");
                                            String latx = Arrays.toString(glatn).replace("[","");
                                            latx = latx.replace("]","");
                                            latx = latx.replace(", null","");
                                            String loadUrlz = "http://easytechi.info/multigpss.php?usern="+removeusern +"&glatn="+latx;
                                            webview.loadUrl(loadUrlz);
                                            System.out.println(loadUrlz);
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), loadUrlz, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }


                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

            Volley.newRequestQueue(PokeChat.this).add(jsonRequest);
```

LogCat output:

```
09-11 19:50:19.283 18494-18997/ E/Volley: [4913] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
                                                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
                                                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
                                                                                                          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
                                                                                                       Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 
                                                                                                          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
                                                                                                          at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
                                                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
                                                                                                          at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                                                          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 


    09-11 19:50:19.990 18494-18998/ E/Volley: [4914] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
                                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
                                                                                                           Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 
                                                                                                              at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
                                                                                                              at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112) 
09-11 19:54:04.878 18494-18999/ E/Volley: [4915] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
                                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL 
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:144)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
                                                                                                           Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 
                                                                                                              at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
                                                                                                              at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:102)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                                                                                              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Comment: does your token contain any / ,?, or = in it ?

Comment: You can't really try-catch this error. It's going to  `onErrorResponse`. Also Protocol not found means it's trying to find the `http://`

Comment: @SukritKumar No. Not at all. I tried Toast messaging the URL and it doesn't have any special characters.

Comment: @cricket_007 exactly, I thought the same but other threads on SO suggested so I tried.

Comment: @cricket_007 as you can see in the code, I have included the http:// now what else do I need to do?

Comment: Can you give a proper url which you call ? One that is outputted in the Toast

Comment: @SukritKumar just because I am adding http:// and its taking it as a link dont think I didn't add http://